# Update h:outputText with escape="false" and value, that contains '\u001c'

Tags: jsf

I have the following Java code:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    private String stringValue;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        initStringValueDefault();
    }

    public void initStringValue1() {
        stringValue = "ABCD";
    }

    public void initStringValue2() {
        stringValue = "EFGH" + '\u001c';
    }

    public void initStringValueDefault() {
        stringValue = "LABEL TEXT";
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

and .xhtml

```
<h:form id="testForm" prependId="true">
    <h:outputText id="stringValueLabel" value="#{testClass.stringValue}" escape="false"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Set ABCD" actionListener="#{testClass.initStringValue1()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="stringValueLabel"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <span style="margin-left: 10px"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Set EFGH + \u001c" actionListener="#{testClass.initStringValue2()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="stringValueLabel"/>
    </h:commandButton>
    <span style="margin-left: 10px"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Set default" actionListener="#{testClass.initStringValueDefault()}">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="stringValueLabel"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When I click on the 'Set ABCD' button, update works successfully. But after click on the 'Set EFGH + \u001c' I get errors:

1. Chrome: 'The page at localhost:8080 says: emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.'
2. Firefox: 'malformedXML: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed'

and the label haven't been updated. And after page reload the label updates to 'EFGH'.

Anybody knows, why due to adding '\u001c' to the variable, update doesn't work after button click?

With escape="true" everything works fine, but I need escape="false".

Comment: are you saying it works without `f:ajax`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by treating the variable with method escapeXml11(String input) of org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11;
...
    public void initStringValue2() {
        stringValue = "EFGH" + '\u001c';
        stringValue = escapeXml11(stringValue);
    }
...
```